# java.lang.StackOverflowError in context with UCanAccess and JPA

Tags: jpa, ucanaccess

When I try to perform a JPA-Query, the UCanAccess Driver quits with a java.lang.StackOverflowError.

This used call is as simple as can be. With another Table this db request works fine.

```
final Tbltitel entity = (Tbltitel) entityManager.createNamedQuery("Tbltitel.findById")
   .setParameter("id", new Integer(14199)).getSingleResult();
```

The call with plain JDBC and the call via Jackcess against this table works also fine, so I guess, something went wrong with the UCanAccess Driver in Context with JPA.

A complete Eclipse Project with the Database and the JUnit Tests can be downloaded at "https://app.box.com/s/mun1se9y7gji24kg6xrx"

My set up:
Windows 7 Professional 64 bit
Microsoft Office 2013
NetBeans IDE 8.0
Java 1.8
UCanAccess-2.0.7-bin

Comment: Okey Martin, I was just releasing the 2.0.7.1 but I want to investigate on this before...

Comment: The query on the table TBLTITEL and the following queries, executed to load the references(about 7) are all executed without problems by UCanAccess. The issue seems to be after the jdbc calls to UCanAccess, while EclipseLink is mapping from  resultset to object. So it don't seem to be UCanAccess related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said this issue seems to be related to EclipseLink and not to UCanAccess.
Setting the annotation @Cacheable(false) on the class Tbllistofvalues, which is autoreferential, should solve the issue.